# How decryption password, which use pbkdf2?

Tags: c#, encryption, pbkdf2

I want to decrypt password in program.
For this I decompile files of this program and find needed code.

Next code call, wheen I create new user to grid.

```
private void SetPasswordCallback(PropertyAdapterBase adapter, object propertyValue)
{
    string text = propertyValue as string;
    if ((Permissions & 0x20000) > 0)
    {
        WebServerAttributeUtilities.QueryFailSafePassword(base.Container.ConfigObject);
    }
    if (text != null)
    {
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        string text2 = text;
        string text3 = text2;
        foreach (char c in text3)
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        secureString.MakeReadOnly();
        Password = GetEncryptedPassword(secureString);
        secureString.Dispose();
        if (WebServerAttributeUtilities.IsWebServerFeatureSupported(base.Container.ConfigObject, WebServerFeatures.UserManagementAsomFullUpload))
        {
            IsEmptyPw = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Password = propertyValue as byte[];
    }
    PasswordConfirmation = Password;
    base.Container.WriteToConfigObject();
    if (m_PropertyAdapterPassword != null)
    {
        RefreshPropertyAdapter(m_PropertyAdapterPassword);
    }
}
```

I find GetEncryptedPassword function. I would to say, program always use pbkdf2 and never go to other if branc. v4 not used, don't see there.

```
public byte[] GetEncryptedPassword(SecureString password)
{
    MD5Encryptor.Encrypt(WebServerAttributeUtilities.ConvertToUnsecureString(password), out var encryptedStr);
    string convertedString = WebServerAttributeUtilities.ConvertToUnsecureString(password);          
    if (WebServerAttributeUtilities.IsWebServerFeatureSupported(base.Container.ConfigObject, WebServerFeatures.UserManagementAsomFullUpload))
    {
        AttributeAccessCode attributeAccessCode = new AttributeAccessCode();
 base.Container.ConfigObject.AttributeAccess.GetAnyAttribute("WebServer.UserManagementIsUpgradedToPbkdf2", attributeAccessCode, 0);
        if (WebServerAttributeUtilities.IsWebServerFeatureSupported(base.Container.ConfigObject, WebServerFeatures.UserManagementUsingPBKDF2) && !attributeAccessCode.IsOkay)
        {
            byte[] pbkdf2Password = WebServerAttributeUtilities.CalculatePasswordForUserManagementPBKDF2(base.Container.ConfigObject, password);
            return WebServerAttributeUtilities.CalculatePasswordForUserManagementPBKDF2(base.Container.ConfigObject, password);
        }
        byte[] v4Password = WebServerAttributeUtilities.CalculatePasswordForUserManagementV4(base.Container.ConfigObject, encryptedStr);
        return WebServerAttributeUtilities.CalculatePasswordForUserManagementV4(base.Container.ConfigObject, encryptedStr);
    }
    return encryptedStr;
}
```

I know CalculatePasswordForUserManagementPBKDF2 function, which use CalcuatePasswordForUserManagement.

```
public static byte[] CalculatePasswordForUserManagementPBKDF2(IConfigBase configObject, SecureString pw)
{
    return CalcuatePasswordForUserManagement(configObject, pw, 2u);

}
```

```
private static byte[] CalcuatePasswordForUserManagement(IConfigBase configObject, SecureString pw, uint algorithmVersion)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[0];
    using (CsiInterop csiInterop = InitializeEncryption(configObject, false))
    {
        if (csiInterop != null)
        {
            csiInterop.AlgorithmVersion = algorithmVersion;
            csiInterop.AddHash = false;
            return csiInterop.CalculatePasswordDigest(pw);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And go to next function.

```
public unsafe byte[] CalculatePasswordDigest(SecureString password)
{
    //Discarded unreachable code: IL_0241
    //IL_005c: Expected I, but got I8
    //IL_005c: Expected I, but got I8
    //IL_007c: Expected I4, but got I8
    //The blocks IL_0000, IL_0000, IL_00db, IL_00e6, IL_010c, IL_013b, IL_0143, IL_0147, IL_0160, IL_017e, IL_0199, IL_01aa, IL_01af, IL_01c0, IL_01c3 are reachable both inside and outside the pinned region starting at IL_00b1. ILSpy has duplicated these blocks in order to place them both within and outside the `fixed` statement.
     //The blocks IL_01af, IL_01c0, IL_01c3 are reachable both inside and outside the pinned region starting at IL_0106. ILSpy has duplicated these blocks in order to place them both within and outside the `fixed` statement.
     //The blocks IL_01af, IL_01c0, IL_01c3 are reachable both inside and outside the pinned region starting at IL_0106. ILSpy has duplicated these blocks in order to place them both within and outside the `fixed` statement.
     uint value = 0u;
     uint num = 0u;
     uint num2 = 0u;
     byte[] array = new byte[0];
     byte[] array2 = array;
     byte[] buffer = array;
     int num3 = 0;
     int num4 = 0;
     sbyte* ptr;
     if (password != null)
     {
         IntPtr s = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
         int num5 = password.Length * 4;
         ptr = (sbyte*)_003CModule_003E.malloc((ulong)(num5 + 1));
         num3 = _003CModule_003E.WideCharToMultiByte(65001u, 0u, (char*)s.ToPointer(), -1, ptr, num5, null, null) - 1;
         Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(s);
         num4 = num3;
     }
     else
     {
         ptr = (sbyte*)_003CModule_003E.malloc(4uL);
         // IL initblk instruction
         System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned(ptr, 0, 4);
     }
     sbyte* ptr2 = ptr;
     uint algorithmVersion = m_AlgorithmVersion;
     if (algorithmVersion >= 1 && algorithmVersion <= 3)
     {
         MemoryStream memoryStream;
         BinaryWriter binaryWriter;
         if (m_AddHash || algorithmVersion == 1)
         {
             byte[] array3 = new byte[20];
             fixed (byte* ptr3 = &array3[0])
             {
                 _003CModule_003E.SHA1((byte*)ptr, (ulong)num3, ptr3);
                 array = EncryptAttribute(array3).Data.Val;
                 num4 = array3.Length;
                 ptr2 = (sbyte*)ptr3;
                 switch (m_AlgorithmVersion)
                 {
                     case 2u:
                         value = 2000u;
                         num = 32u;
                         num2 = 32u;
                         buffer = new byte[32];
                         fixed (byte* ptr4 = &buffer[0])
                         {                        _003CModule_003E.Siemens_002ESimatic_002EHwConfiguration_002EBasics_002ECsiInterop_002ECsiCallback_002EGenerateRandom(ptr4, 32u);
                             array2 = new byte[32];
                             fixed (byte* ptr5 = &array2[0])
                             {
                                 _003CModule_003E.PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(ptr2, num4, ptr4, 32, 2000, _003CModule_003E.EVP_sha256(), 32, ptr5);
                                 _003CModule_003E.InternalFreeBuffer(ptr, (ulong)num3);
                                 if (m_AlgorithmVersion == 1)
                                 {
                                     return array;
                                 }
                                 memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                                 binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)256);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)1);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)array.Length);
                                 binaryWriter.Write(array);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)m_AlgorithmVersion);
                                 binaryWriter.Write(value);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)num);
                                 binaryWriter.Write(buffer);
                                 binaryWriter.Write((ushort)num2);
                                 binaryWriter.Write(array2);
                                 binaryWriter.Close();
                                 return memoryStream.ToArray();
                             }
                         }
...
```

It's not all code, but i think that's enogh. Next cases not uses.
I stop there and really don't know what do next. In last function used random number (*_003CModule_003E.Siemens_002ESimatic_002EHwConfiguration_002EBasics_002ECsiInterop_002ECsiCallback_002EGenerateRandom(ptr4, 32u);*) and this scared me.

With debugging I find field *password*, which type is byte[80]. How can I know, it's need to decrypt. Can you help me?

Comment: Nice try! I was about to post an answer with a possible exploit but then I noticed you're trying to hack someone.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Why hack? Ok, if you want a some details... It's my task in work. Some employee not remember his password. And no one try to find or create new password is not work. I don't want say all about this work, because it;s too long. And it's my work, i'm not a hacker

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I'm junior, maybe trany, *i'm not sure*. what kind of hacker am I? But thanks for the compliment

Comment: Never said you're a hacker (then you wouldn't have to ask). Just said you're *trying* to hack someone.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my task, but I think that answer will be unusefull.

I framed decompile library to work project and debug this. On open user grid decompile code stop on function, which contain password. As I said, this password was byte[80] and use pbkdf2. I with my collegue find how realese pbkdf2 function. In arguments we find length of salt. And crypt password was in last 32 bytes in password.

We have salt and result of crypting. I use enumeration.Fortunately, my collegue know, that password have only numbers. Because of that we find this password.